# How to store user Login details(user, pass) for multiple accounts on iPhone app

Tags: iphone, autosave, autologin, loginview

I have an iPhone application that requires the user to login(username, password). 
I currently store the credentials of the last succesful login and fill the textfields the next time the user launches the app.

Alot of the times though the user may have more than one account and I now need to implement something to store login credentials for more accounts.

How would you suggest that I do that? I looked around but I couldn't find anything related to this.

Answer (score 1):

NSUserDefaults or Storing into sqllite or Storing into a plist are on of the ways of storing persistent data. But they are not secure. I will recommend Key Chain Access for storing secure data.

This link provides a apple sample code which uses key chain Access

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/GenericKeychain/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40007797-Intro-DontLinkElementID_2

But one disadvantage is you cant test this in simulator it works only on device i think.

You can also add multiple items to the keychain.

Comment: Testing on the device is not a problem.
However my question was more about, How I can give the user the option to add new, select existing, or delete existing login credentials. The question is more about how to give the user the ability to enter and maintain the login credentials in a user-friendly way.

Comment: Just a idea from me. Keep a remember me option. If the user selects remember me and logins, store the values(add new). When the user selects the username textfield get all the names from the storage and show it under a picker(select existing). When the user signsout prompt a alertview that the user credentials should be saved or notsaved(delete).  Jst a thought tats all.

Answer (score 0):

Look `NSUserDefaults` at the [documentation](http://icodeblog.com/2008/10/03/iphone-programming-tutorial-savingretrieving-data-using-nsuserdefaults/).

Maybe this tuto can help you : http://icodeblog.com/2008/10/03/iphone-programming-tutorial-savingretrieving-data-using-nsuserdefaults/

Comment: Thanks for the prompt responces. This is great info. 
However my question was more regarding the interface rather than the storage itself. 
Basically Im not sure how to give the user the option to enter his login details or choose from stored login details.
What can you recommend?

Answer (score 0):

Try with [CoreData](http://iphoneinaction.manning.com/iphone_in_action/core-data/)...

Comment: Wow!!! Way out of my head! Is Core Data really necessary? 
Again I must stress out that I was interested in your thoughts about the objects and views used to get the data from the user. ie the interface you would recommend. For example text fields to enter the data in combination with a table view to select from existing and something else that would allow the user to delete from stored list of login details.
My experience on iPhone Dev is limited.